# What is a good way to count source lines of code (SLOC) in a CoffeeScript project?

Tags: coffeescript

Is there a common way of counting source lines of code (SLOC) in a CoffeeScript project?

I'm hoping for something that will traverse all of the directories in my project during the count.  I found a few projects online but they seemed kind of overkill for the task.  I would love a simple utility or even just some command-line-fu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're on UNIX, I would go with the `wc` tool.  I usually use `wc -l *.coffee */*.coffee etc.` because it is easy to remember.  However, a recursive version would be

```
wc -l `find <proj-dir> -type f | grep \.coffee$`
```

which runs the `find command`, which recursively lists files of type `f`, or normal files, fed into the `grep`, which filters down to just Coffeescript files, and the output of that is used as the command line arguments to `wc` (`-l` signals a line count).

Edit:  Now we don't want to count blank or comment lines (we're only catching single-line comments here).  We lose the per-file counts, but here goes:

```
cat `find <proj-dir> -type f | grep \.coffee$` | sed '/^\s*#/d;/^\s*$/d' | wc -l
```

We find the Coffeescript files, and then `cat` them.  Then, `sed` strips out lines that consist of only whitespace or have whitespace followed by a `#`.  Finally, our friend `wc` counts the remaining lines.

Comment: This is great!  But just to be picky: any chance of a solution that will omit blank lines and lines that begin with "#" for __source__ lines of code?  I don't think I use the block comment anywhere in my code (###) so that would be all I need.

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want: https://github.com/blackducksw/ohcount

It correctly excludes comments and blank lines and also supports many other languages.